# Linear independence of the set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{(a_{ij},...,a_{in}) \in T^n \mid i = 1,...,s \le n\}$ be a set of vectors. Prove that if $$|a_{jj}| \gt \sum_{i=1, i\neq j}^s|a_{ij}|, \quad 1 \leq j \leq s$$ then the set is linearly independent.

**My attempt:** I was trying an example with $n=s=3$,

$|a_{11}| \gt $$\sum_{i=1, i\neq j}^{n=3}|a_{i1}|= |a_{21}|+|a_{31}|$

$|a_{22}| \gt $$\sum_{i=1, i\neq j}^{n=3}|a_{i1}|= |a_{12}|+|a_{32}|$

$|a_{33}| \gt $$\sum_{i=1, i\neq j}^{n=3}|a_{i1}|= |a_{13}|+|a_{23}|$

For the linear independence we would have to satisfy, that $x=y=z=0$

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
        \end{pmatrix}  
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        z \\
        \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

But I just don't know what's next. Like the $|a_{jj}|$ are on the places where are pivots and if these elements are after Gauss elimination nonzero, then our given set in linearly independent. But I don't know how to prove it. Thanks for help.

Comment: What is $T$? See [Geršgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).

Comment: Not sure but I think it is just division ring or the number field. I don't know how to translate if from my language but we are working with it as with the real numbers.

Comment: It's weird because nothing about the problem claims you only have have three vectors in the particular case of $n=s=3$. If $T=\mathbb R$, then the set is infinite.

Comment: I just tried to visualizate it, I don't understand that example very much.

Comment: My point was that if the set is infinite, given the context, it most likely is linearly dependent.

Comment: @GitGud Probably my edit inadvertently caused a confusion, OP probably meant $$\{(a_{11},...,a_{1n}),\ldots,(a_{s1},...,a_{sn})\}$$

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic Ohhh, this makes much more sense now. **Edit:** And your edit wasn't the issue.

Comment: But it is not in my textbook like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about [Diagonal-dominant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), which are non-singular. You can show this, as pointed out in the commets, by using Gersgorin-circles.

Comment: I have never heard about it, but I will try, thank you. My example is from the basic course of linear algebra.

Comment: These parts of linear algebra are more advanced then I have ever encountered yet, so I think I will leave it.